# Форма ant design поля переносятся на следующую строку после label

Tags: reactjs, ant-design

Беру код прямо со страницы antd с примерами;
При этом поля (fields) отображаются на следующей строке после label ? Как исправить ?
(функциональный компонент)

```
  const layout = {
    labelCol: { span: 4 },
    wrapperCol: { span: 14 },
  }
  const antForm = () => {
    return (
    <div>
      <Form {...layout} form={form} name="detailedInfo" onFinish={onFinish}>
        <Form.Item name="id" label="id#">
          <Input />
        </Form.Item>
        <Form.Item name="type" label="Ресурс">
          <Input />
        </Form.Item>   
    </div>
    )
  }
```

[image: Так выглядит форма]

Answer (score 0):

Забыл сделать импорт

```
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
```